# MultiSubnetFailover for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, jdbc

Does anyone know how to construct the database connection string with multisubnet failover as true? We are trying to connect to a SQL Server which is on AOAG (Always on availability group).

We are trying to connect via application where we are using org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource to create a data source bean and then using it in application.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${DRIVER_CLASS}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${JDBC_URL}"/>
    <property name="username" value="{userName}"/>
    <property name="password" value="{******}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: We are using spring manager data source to create database beans <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${DRIVER_CLASS}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${JDBC_URL}"/>
        <property name="username" value="{userName}"/>
        <property name="password" value="{******}"/>
    </bean>

Comment: Try typing your title into google....first hit has the answer , right there.....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
MultiSubnetFailover=True
```

From [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017#SupportAgMultiSubnetFailover)